# Setting up a mailing list repository in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, email

I'm trying to set up (in Sharepoint), a mailing list archive. What I'd like it to do is listen for mails to the mailing list and archive them as searchable documents within the sharepoint site. More or less, the Microsoft equivalent of this:

http://www.biglist.com/lists/stella/archives/

Are there any good ways to do this? We're running the 2007 versions of Sharepoint and Exchange, if I understand our admins correctly.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SharePoint 2007 - Incoming email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/neilth/sharepoint-2007-incoming-email)

In particular this is very good

[How to configure email enabled lists in Moss2007 using Exchange 2007 (PDF)](https://web.archive.org/web/20121207064735/http://www.combined-knowledge.com:80/Downloads/2007/How%20to%20configure%20Email%20Enabled%20Lists%20in%20Moss2007%20RTM%20using%20Exchange%202007.pdf)